# C - pointer arithmetics

Tags: c, pointers

I have:

```
char buffer[512 + 12];
```

And I'm trying to force `buffer` to be 16 bytes alligned (meaning - zero it's last 4 bits).
So I tried:

```
buffer = (char*)(((uint32_t)buffer +12)) & ~0xF);
```

But I'm getting `incompatible types in assignment`

I'm guessing this is because char[] and char* aren't the same type. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why not ask the compiler to align it?

Comment: You're trying to change the base address of an array. Declare a pointer with different name.

Comment: While this is not an answer to your question, you probably should be using [`__attribute__((aligned(16)))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)(GCC) /[`posix_memalign`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_memalign.html), or [`__declspec(align(16))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx)/[`_aligned_malloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx)(Windows) instead.

Comment: I'm using neither Linux nor Windows.

Comment: Then you need to specify what compiler you're using. Alignment is compiler-specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you need to add 15 bytes, not 12, and it should be:

```
char _buffer[512 + 15];

char * const buffer = (char*)(((uintptr_t)_buffer + 15)) & ~0xF);
```

Note that the original buffer address can not be modified so we call the unaligned buffer `_buffer` and initialise a const aligned pointer, `buffer`, at the first aligned address within `_buffer`.

At the expense of portability you can also use compiler extensions to do the same thing a lot more simply, e.g. in gcc and gcc-compatible compilers:

```
char buffer[512] __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
```

Comment: buffer has to be of type char buffer[] since I can't use dynamic allocation at this point of the code.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice the _. Thanks!